# Upvote and Downvote buttons with Django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to make upvote and downvote buttons for comments but I want all the form inputs that django.contrib.comments.forms.CommentSecurityForm gives me to make sure the form is secure. Is that necessary? And if so, how do I make a form class that with upvote and downvote buttons? Custom checkbox styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest, you use separate view login for up and down voting.

Something like this `/upvote/{{comment.pk|urlize}}`

and then write a view that works with this url. With PK find the comment that the user is trying to up/down vote, then write the necessary condition to check if the user is authorized to perform that kind of action, and then finally execute that action.

I hope this helps

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear, all of that is working (except the login, since I want anonymous voting, but I check a set cookie to make sure they aren't voting more than once). The only thing I'm unsure of is how to change what is currently a select form (with an option to upvote or downvote and then a submit button) into two buttons while still retaining the security features of CommentSecurityForm. Are you saying I don't need those features? because if so that would be great.

Comment: After thinking I bit more I think I understand what you're saying. Should I just add two buttons that run an ajax function and have the buttons pass them the primary key and then check on the view side to make sure they haven't already upvoted the comment (using cookies)?

Comment: yes Jake. that would be ideal in my opinion.primary key would help you find the exact comment that you are looking for. then it doesn't matter if the user is registered or not. with cookies at the views end, you can check if the user has voted before or not